# While function stuck in loop, seems that half of loop doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm struggling today with a loop function for a project I have about liquid democracy. While delegating the votes, I have a while loop to check that no delegations was forgotten, this algorithm has an interesting behavior:

```js
Vote.count({
  propId: propId,
  delegation: true
}, function(err, voteNumber) {
  var maxDelegation = voteNumber;
  for (var d = 1; d < maxDelegation + 1; d++) {
    var delegationsLeft = 1; //Is calculated to see if someone delegates to a delegate
    while (delegationsLeft > 0) {
      console.log("I am about to find the votes for " + d + " weight, " + delegationsLeft + " delegation left at least.");
      Vote.find({
        propId: propId,
        delegation: true,
        weight: d
      }, function(err, specWeightVotes) {
        console.log("I'm in.");
        delegationsLeft = specWeightVotes.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < specWeightVotes.length; i++) {
          // Add the weight d, aka the weight of a vote to the delegated voter
          Vote.findOneAndUpdate({
            propId: propId,
            voter: specWeightVotes[i].content
          }, {
            $inc: {
              'weight': specWeightVotes[i].weight
            }
          }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Ca bug.");
            }

            //Put weight as zero for the ones who have delegated
            Vote.findOneAndUpdate({
              _id: specWeightVotes[i]._id
            }, {
              $set: {
                'weight': 0
              }
            }, function(err) {
              if (err) {
                console.log("Ca bug 2.");
              }
            });

          });

        }
      });

    }
  }
  console.log("I have delegated all votes");
});
```

Now the interesting thing here is that my while loop is stuck forever because it never gets to execute the `Vote.find({propId: propId, delegation: true, weight: d}, function(err, specWeightVotes){` part of the code.

If I look at the console, I have the following output:

```
I am about to find the votes for 1 weight, 1 delegation left at least.
I am about to find the votes for 1 weight, 1 delegation left at least.
I am about to find the votes for 1 weight, 1 delegation left at least.
I am about to find the votes for 1 weight, 1 delegation left at least.
I am about to find the votes for 1 weight, 1 delegation left at least.
```

... until eventually the process runs out of battery. I never get to see a  "I'm in" part.

I suppose this could be solved with some more asynchronous programming maybe? However, considering my function doesn't execute even once, I'm not sure.

PS: Important note, before including this while loop to prevent delegations to be forgotten, the algorithm was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `Vote.find` does its work *asynchronously* (and similarly for `Vote.findOneAndUpdate`). Your `for` and `while` loops do not. So `delegationsLeft` will never be anything but 1 during the course of your loop.

If you're interacting with asynchronous results, you can't use `while` (or `for` or `do-while`). Instead, you need to schedule the next "iteration" of the "loop" from within the asynchronous callback.

(Or put all of the code into an ES2017+ `async` function, wrap `Vote.find` and such in wrappers that return Promises, and use `await`. But that requires a cutting-edge JavaScript environment to run in, or transpiling with something like [Babel](http://babeljs.io).)

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer, I had no idea. Do you think something like a recursive function would work for such problem? I will try it now and let you know, but just in case I get on a dead end right away, I'd rather know.

Comment: @AdrienMerlier: Yes, that's the usual way to handle it. In your case you have three nested loops so it's fairly complicated. I'd encourage you to try to break the logic up into smaller pieces, which will help with writing the recursive functions.